# Windows Form C# Button blink On and Off

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have this game in Windows Form that displays 9 buttons on the screen, you have to guess the number the computer thinks, if the number is correct the button should blink/flash on and off. I looked out but i couldn't find any relevant function to help me out. If someone can help me I would really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: add more details to your question

Comment: You'll probably need to use a timer. Try it yourself and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: You want to make a control blink. You're right in that you couldn't find any ready-made solution for that, the framework doesn't have such a method or property. This will happen a lot in your future programming career, so you'd better learn what to do next: write down what you actually want to happen. _"Make something blink"_ means _"make something visible for a short amount of time, then hide it for a short amount of time, ad infinitum"_. If you then search the web for _"winforms hide control"_ and _"winforms timer"_, you have successfully broken up your problem in solvable parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which switches the background color of your buttons on the 
`Elapsed` event.

Sample code:

```
// Create a timer with a ten second interval.
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

The `OnTimeEvent` function:

```
void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change button color
}
```

Hope it helps :-)